# Mongosh not using the updated MongoDB version

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm using ubuntu.
I had MongoDB v4.0.28 before and also some unimportant test-dbs on the drive. Then I installed Mongosh, and then I updated MongoDB to 5.0.6.
Wenn I start mongosh, it says "Using MongoDB: 4.0.28"
Should I do something ti make Mongosh to use MongoDB 5.0.6?
Btw. `apt list --installed` looks like this:

```
mongodb-mongosh/focal,now 1.1.9 amd64 [installed]
mongodb-org-database-tools-extra/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-org-database/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-org-mongos/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-org-server/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-org-shell/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-org-tools/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-org/focal,now 5.0.6 amd64 [installed]
```

edit: When I try to start mongosh today, I get `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` instead.

edit2: I found out what I did wrong. I followed the steps under "Install MongoDB", but then I didn't continue to the "Run MongoDB" part... now it works.

Comment: check what the command "which mongosh" show to understand which binary you are using  by default  , most probably this is /usr/bin/mongosh that could be older version , or your path maybe find another location where the version is identified first , check with echo $PATH the available path ... , you may need to remove some older deployment path ...

Comment: When I try to start mongosh today, I get `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so it can be marked as solved.. I found out what I did wrong. I followed the steps under "Install MongoDB", but then I didn't continue to the "Run MongoDB" part... now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to uninstall both mongodb and mongosh by following instruction from the official site, then try to reinstall the both mongosh and mongodb (latest versions) stable..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).